# Ubuntu installer uninstalls packages at end-how to stop this?

Tags: system-installation, 14.10

I'm using the Ubuntu live CD to install Ubuntu 14.10.

I noticed one of the last things it does is uninstalls packages. E.g., I see "Uninstalling gparted..." and more in the status bar.

Is there any way I can tell the installer DON'T do this uninstall step?

Comment: What? The *Un-installer* is actually *un-installing* packages? Maybe a screenshot/paste of what's running and what's happening could clear this up...

Comment: @Xen2050 at the end of installation, packages that are useful for installation but not needed for the installed OS are removed, including GParted, ubiquity itself, some language packs and so on.

Comment: Must be typo in the subject, "*uninstaller uninstalls*", I'll edit to "Installer"

Comment: Yep, thanks, sorry :) Wrote that late at night from a phone :)

Comment: @Muru: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby that's not an answer. OP is asking how to prevent ubiquity from doing so. I was merely explaining to Xen2050 what was happening.

Comment: @Muru: I bow to my god: Answer deleted!  notfed: I'm good at reading between the lines, and sometimes I read *too much*  between the lines (that's what you get from dealing with people who don't know what they want!)  ;-)